# Odd number of equally spaced vectors

Tags: vectors

When three vectors equally spaced out that is make an angle of 120° and placed tail to tail the vectors cancel out and have a net effect of zero.

Can this be generalized to all positive odd number of vectors equally spaced out .(excluding just 1 vector)

If so can it be proved ?

Comment: Are proof questions not allowed ? Sorry I am not aware of the site's policies .

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic it's ok sir/ma'am I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With N vectors of equal magnitude, the number does not need to be odd.  If the angle from one vector to the next = 360/N degrees, they will form a closed figure. (consider a square.)

Comment: Mind blown ,thank you !